# rspec rails, instance should match an element from an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, rspec

I have a Panel class which has an array. All instances of that class have to contain one of the elements of that array.

```
  TEXT_ONLY = "text_only"
  IMAGE_LEFT = "image_left"
  IMAGE_RIGHT = "image_right"
  IMAGE_ONLY = "image_only"
  VIDEO = "video"
  PANEL_TYPE = [TEXT_ONLY, IMAGE_LEFT, IMAGE_RIGHT, IMAGE_ONLY, VIDEO]

  validate :panel_type, inclusion: PANEL_TYPE.each
```

I am trying to write a test that matches this validation.

```
  mandatory_string_from_collection :panel_type, CorporatePanel::PANEL_TYPE.each

  def mandatory_string_from_collection(method,collection)
    context "#{method} is a mandatory string" do
      exists(method)
      it "should reject a blank #{method}" do
        @instance.send("#{method}=","")
        expect(@instance).not_to be_valid
      end
      context "where the value is not within the acceptable options" do
        it "should reject it" do
          @instance.send("#{method}=","zgodnflax")
          expect(@instance).to_not be_valid
        end
      end
      context "where the value is within the acceptable options" do
        it "should accept it" do
          @instance.send("#{method}=",collection.first)
          expect(@instance).to be_valid
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Here is the factory

this i my factory

```
factory :corporate_panel do
    corporate_page
    section 1
    panel_type "video"
    title "MyString"
    headline "MyString"
    body "MyText"
    # workflow_state "MyString"
  end
```

the test yields this, and i do not understand why?!

```
 1) CorporatePanel panel_type is a mandatory string should reject a blank panel_type
     Failure/Error: expect(@instance).not_to be_valid
       expected #<CorporatePanel id: 353, corporate_page_id: 464, section: 1, position: 1, panel_type: "", title: "MyString", headline: "MyString", body: "MyText", workflow_state: "draft", created_at: "2014-08-11 22:49:26", updated_at: "2014-08-11 22:49:26", asset_id: nil> not to be valid
     # -e:1:in `<main>'

  2) CorporatePanel panel_type is a mandatory string where the value is not within the acceptable options should reject it
     Failure/Error: expect(@instance).to_not be_valid
       expected #<CorporatePanel id: 355, corporate_page_id: 466, section: 1, position: 1, panel_type: "zgodnflax", title: "MyString", headline: "MyString", body: "MyText", workflow_state: "draft", created_at: "2014-08-11 22:49:26", updated_at: "2014-08-11 22:49:26", asset_id: nil> not to be valid
```

Comment: what's the "each" for? (in the model-class, not the spec)

Comment: @TarynEast to test against each element of the array

Comment: as i said - not the each in the spec... the each in the *model*. I'm pretty sure that shouldn't be there.

Comment: In fact - the `each` in the spec doesn't make sense either. not where you've got it... you aren't iterating through the `PANEL_TYPE`s the way you've written it... I think you might misunderstand what `each` actually does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
validate :panel_type, inclusion: PANEL_TYPE.each
```

should just be

```
validate :panel_type, inclusion: PANEL_TYPE
```

You are validating that `panel_type` is in the set `PANEL_TYPE` (also, I'd call it `PANEL_TYPES` because there's more than one in the set)

Secondly, you do not want to do this each either

```
mandatory_string_from_collection :panel_type, CorporatePanel::PANEL_TYPE.each
```

if what you want is "I want to check that for each `PANEL_TYPE` that it is ok to use" then what you probably want is this:

```
CorporatePanel::PANEL_TYPE.each do |panel_type|
  mandatory_string_from_collection :panel_type, panel_type
end
```